# Inner join on 2 columns for two dataframes python

Tags: python, join, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes named `geostat` and `geostat_query`. I am trying to do inner join on 2 columns. The code that I have written is giving me empty result.

My dataframes are:

**geostat:**

```
        STATE COUNT PERCENT  state pool number STATE CODE  
0                  0.00                251         CA         
1                  0.00                252         CA         
2                  0.00                253         CA         
3                  0.00                787         CA         
4                  0.00                789         CA         
5                  0.00               4401         CA         
6                  0.00               4402         CA         
7                  0.00               4403         CA         
8                  0.00               4404         CA         
9                  0.00               4406         CA         
10                 0.00               4568         CA         
11                 0.00               4569         FL         
12                 0.00               4576         CA         
13                 0.00               4577         CA         
14                 0.00               4578         CA         
15                 0.00               4579         CA         
16                 0.00               4580         CA         
17                 0.00               4581         CA         
18                 0.00               4582         CA         
19                 0.00               4584         CA         
20                 0.00               4585         CA         
21                 0.00               4588         CA         
22                 0.00               4589         CA         
23                 0.00               4591         CA         
24                 0.00               4592         CA         
25                 0.00               4593         CA         
26                 0.00               4594         FL         
27                 0.00               4595         CA         
28                 0.00               4595         FL         
29                 0.00               6221         MS         
30                 0.00             817085         GA         
31                 0.03             817085         IL         
32                 0.03             817085         IN         
33                 0.03             817085         MA         
34                 0.03             817085         ME         
35                 0.07             817085         MI         
36                 0.07             817085         MO         
37                 0.03             817085         NE         
38                 0.07             817085         OH         
39                 0.03             817085         PA         
40                 0.03             817085         SC         
41                 0.03             817085         SD         
42                 0.03             817085         TX         
43                 0.07             817085         WI         
44                 0.08             817094         AL         
45                 0.09             817094         CA
```

**geostat_query:**

```
            MaxOfState count percent  state pool number 
0                        100                251         
1                        100                252         
2                        100                253         
3                        100                787         
4                        100                789         
5                        100               4401         
6                        100               4402         
7                        100               4403         
8                        100               4404         
9                        100               4406         
10                       100               4568         
11                       100               4569         
12                       100               4576         
13                       100               4577         
14                       100               4578         
15                       100               4579         
16                       100               4580         
17                       100               4581         
18                       100               4582         
19                       100               4584         
20                       100               4585         
21                       100               4588         
22                       100               4589         
23                       100               4591         
24                       100               4592         
25                       100               4593         
26                       100               4594         
27                        75               4595         
28                       100               6221         
29                       100               8194
```

The code I wrote is :

```
 geomerge = geostat.merge(geostat_query, left_on=['STATE COUNT PERCENT','state pool number'], right_on=['MaxOfState count percent','state pool number'],how='inner')
```

But this gives me empty result. I dont understand where am I going wrong?